# Drop down menu not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu

My CiviCRM drop down menu is not working in my WordPress Dashboard. Hence, I can't access membership info, etc. How do I know if it is a hosting problem or a CiviCRM problem? My host says it doesn't support plug-ins.

Wendy

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache, rebuild menu, etc?

Comment: Hi Wendy, can you add the version of CiviCRM and WordPress. That information helps to make the answers more specific. And do you use a specific WordPress template? Sometimes the javascript of a template does not work with the javascript of CiviCRM. Check if you see errors in the javascript console.

Comment: Also try accessing the sandpit site at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/. This will see if the problem is in your browser. I recently had an odd problem with Firefox where the menus weren't showing and it was fixed by simply restarting Firefox.

Comment: I have cleared the cache but have no clue how to rebuild the menu.

Comment: My versions are:  Powered by CiviCRM 5.11.0. System Status: Error . WordPress version is: 5.1.1.  Shows cron not running. My theme is Compass Pro (Family History theme) by Ink Themes.  When I look at the demo version - I don't get the messages at all when I click on Civi CRM and NONE of my top links have a drop down menu. GoDaddy says it doesn't support plug-ins. Tells me it is the programs fault.